# Confused on a SecureNet response code using cURL

Tags: php, curl, payment-gateway

I have searched Google and StackOverflow about this error, and I am having trouble finding results. Perhaps there is someone out there that can point me in the right direction, as I have never worked with the **SecureNet API** before.

I have a working form in **PHP**, however when submitting it to [SecureNet](https://apidocs.securenet.com/docs/getstarted.html?lang=php), I get this as a ***response***:

```
{"success":false,"result":"AUTHENTICATION_ERROR","responseCode":3,"message":"SecureNetId and SecureNetKey should be passed as Basic authentication tokens or in request object.","responseDateTime":"2015-08-27T02:58:12.54Z","rawRequest":null,"rawResponse":null,"jsonRequest":null}bool(true)
```

Here is my code:

```
    $url = 'https://gwapi.demo.securenet.com/api/Payments/Charge';
$data = array(
    "publickey" => $apiPkey,
    "amount" => $donationAmount,
    "card" => array(
        "number" => $cardNumber,
        "cvv" => $cvv,
        "expirationDate" => $expiryMonth . '/' . $expiryYear,
        "address" => array(
            "line1" => $address,
            "city" => $city,
            "state" => $state,
            "zip" => $zip
        ),
        "firstName" => "Jack",
        "lastName" => "Test"
    ),
    "extendedInformation" => array(
        "typeOfGoods" => "DIGITAL"
    ),
    "developerApplication" => array(
        "developerId" => $apiID,
        "version" => $apiVersion
    )
);

$secureNet = http_build_query($data);

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $secureNet);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

var_dump($result);

curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, I wasn't sending the headers.

```
    $headers = array(
        "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($apidID . ':' . $apiSkey)
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```